# When clicked on icon image (Background Video playing), play the video in popup from where it is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, popup, html5-video

Background Video is playing. When clicked on play icon, Video Should Start playing in popup. But video Should Start playing continuously from when and where it is clicked.

https://jsfiddle.net/Pavankumar_Kori/t1wupLmv/10/

Example :

Background Video is playing (autoplay) if clicked on Play-

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $('#headerVideoLink').magnificPopup({
    type:'inline',
    midClick: true // Allow opening popup on middle mouse click. Always set it to true if you don't provide alternative source in href.
  });
});
```

```css
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

#videoContainer {
  position: absolute;
  min-height: 25rem;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#videoContainer video {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  z-index: 0;
  -ms-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  -moz-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}

#videoContainer .position {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
}

#videoContainer .overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: #000000;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0.4;
  z-index: 1;
}

#headerPopup{
  width:100%;
  margin:0 auto;
}

#headerPopup video{
  width:100%;
  margin:0 auto;
}

.mfp-close-btn-in .mfp-close {
  color: #fff;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/magnific-popup.js/1.0.0/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js"></script><script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/magnific-popup.js/1.0.0/magnific-popup.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link
href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<section id="videoContainer">
  <div class="overlay"></div>
  <video playsinline="playsinline" autoplay="autoplay" muted="muted" loop="loop">
    <source src="https://videos.dailymail.co.uk/video/mol/2015/10/21/404258251173707140/1024x576_404258251173707140.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  </video>
  <div class="container-fluid position h-100">
    <div class="d-flex h-100 text-center align-items-center">
      <div class="w-100">
        <a href="#headerPopup" id="headerVideoLink" target="_blank"><img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/512/0/375.png" alt="Smiley face" height="80" width="80"></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="headerPopup" class="mfp-hide embed-responsive embed-responsive-21by9">
    <video playsinline="playsinline" autoplay="autoplay" controls="controls" muted="muted" loop="loop">
      <source src="https://videos.dailymail.co.uk/video/mol/2015/10/21/404258251173707140/1024x576_404258251173707140.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
  </div>
</section>
```

icon at x secs/mins. In Popup it should start playing continuously from x secs/mins itself

Comment: Do you want update exact time of background video to popup video? I mean you want to play popup video on which time background video is currently playing?

Comment: Yes. Same time. think if i click on 30 Secs. IN popup the video Should Start from 30 Secs. Not from 0 Sec

Comment: You can update your popup video time using `currentTime' javascript function. I have posted my answer. Plz check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use callback function in magnific popup... Then update `currentTime` of background video to popup video using simple javascript.

**Here is Demo**

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $('#headerVideoLink').magnificPopup({
    type:'inline',
    midClick: true, // Allow opening popup on middle mouse click. Always set it to true if you don't provide alternative source in href.
    callbacks: {
      elementParse: function(item) {
        var bannerVid = $('#videoContainer').children('video')[0].currentTime;
        $('#videoContainer').children('video')[0].pause();
        $('#headerPopup').children('video')[0].currentTime = bannerVid;
        $('#headerPopup').children('video')[0].play();
      },
      close: function(){
        var vidTime = $('#headerPopup').children('video')[0].currentTime;
        $('#headerPopup').children('video')[0].pause();
        $('#videoContainer').children('video')[0].currentTime = vidTime;
        $('#videoContainer').children('video')[0].play();
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```css
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

#videoContainer {
  position: absolute;
  min-height: 25rem;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#videoContainer video {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  z-index: 0;
  -ms-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  -moz-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}

#videoContainer .position {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
}

#videoContainer .overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: #000000;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0.4;
  z-index: 1;
}

#headerPopup{
  width:100%;
  margin:0 auto;
}

#headerPopup video{
  width:100%;
  margin:0 auto;
}

.mfp-close-btn-in .mfp-close {
  color: #fff;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/magnific-popup.js/1.0.0/magnific-popup.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/magnific-popup.js/1.0.0/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js"></script>

<section id="videoContainer">
  <div class="overlay"></div>
  <video playsinline="playsinline" autoplay="autoplay" muted="muted" loop="loop">
    <source src="https://videos.dailymail.co.uk/video/mol/2015/10/21/404258251173707140/1024x576_404258251173707140.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  </video>
  <div class="container-fluid position h-100">
    <div class="d-flex h-100 text-center align-items-center">
      <div class="w-100">
        <a href="#headerPopup" id="headerVideoLink" target="_blank"><img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/512/0/375.png" alt="Smiley face" height="80" width="80"></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="headerPopup" class="mfp-hide embed-responsive embed-responsive-21by9">
    <video playsinline="playsinline" autoplay="autoplay" controls="controls" muted="muted" loop="loop">
      <source src="https://videos.dailymail.co.uk/video/mol/2015/10/21/404258251173707140/1024x576_404258251173707140.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Tq @Asfan Shaikh.. But Video is playing in background. It Should Stop playing in background

Comment: You can toggle timings and play/pause events using some javascript video events.

Comment: OK tq. I Will Try

Comment: I have edited my answer just now. Check if it works as you expect.

Comment: @PavankumarKori welcome :) Plz upvote if answer is helpful.

Comment: See this link https://jsfiddle.net/duxLk123/1/ When popup is opened the video starts but the problem is the video will stuck. Ex: when clicked on popup the video will stuck in starting fro some milliseconds and vice versa. can you see once.

Comment: I can't see any video in Popup. When I open `https://gcs-vimeo.akamaized.net/exp=1577685760~acl=%2A%2F678865282.mp4%2A~hmac=5fd756c89fde5690a6ae7c7cb453ce04945fab6ee1ce312e6fee0ba0f96db92d/vimeo-prod-skyfire-std-us/01/168/8/200844169/678865282.mp4` in new tab, it says Access Denied.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Pavankumar_Kori/geajrqpn/3/   Check this link

Comment: Still blocking video to play. It says 'Access Denied'.

Comment: It's OK. I think its video problem. But Thanks a lot. if u don't mind can you share your mail id

Comment: You can connect with me on LinkedIn https://in.linkedin.com/in/asfan-shaikh-254972153